# Only fire Timer event after previous Elapsed event has finished? [c#]

Tags: c#, timer

Is there way to fire the `System.Timers.Timer.Elapsed` only after the previous Elapsed event has finished?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A common pattern to avoid this.

- Start the timer
- Stop it in the beginning of the handler
- Start it again at the end of the handler

This guarantees you can only ever be processing the handler once.

Comment: Awesome, that's a nice and simple solution.

Comment: @Hans, also mentions setting the `AutoReset` property to false. See below.

Answer (score 0):

The [`Timer.Interval`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.interval.aspx) property may be helpful for you.